# variable from a for in array that won't display on my collection view swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview

```
        //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  Fashun
    //
    //  Created by Alex Macleod on 20/10/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Macleod. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        var collectionView: UICollectionView?

        var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()
        var accessToken: NSString!
        var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults!

        // the range represents integer values 0, 1, and 2
        // the range now represents integer values 6, 7, and 8

        let colorWheel = ColorWheel()
        var photoCount: Int! = 0
        var photos: UIImage! = UIImage()

    //    private let api = "d4984c8cfa78689bd066d82bec820fd5"



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            self.accessToken = userDefaults!.objectForKey("accessToken") as NSString
            println(self.accessToken)

            //        instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty = "Hello World"
    //        var accessToken : NSString? = NSString(instanceOfCustomObject.accessToken)
    //        println(accessToken)
    //        instanceOfCustomObject.authorize()
    //        instanceOfCustomObject.simpleAuth()


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    //        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 124, height: 124)
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
            collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            collectionView!.dataSource = self
            collectionView!.delegate = self
            collectionView!.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

            getData()

        }

        func getData() -> Void {
            let baseUrl = NSURL(string:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=\(self.accessToken)")

            let forcastUrl = NSURL(string: "", relativeToURL: baseUrl)

            //        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: forcastUrl)
            //        println(data)
            let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(baseUrl, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


                //            var urlContents = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
                //            println(urlContents)

                let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseUrl)
                //            println(dataObject)
                if (error == nil) {
                    let responseDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

                    var currentResponse = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray
//                    println(currentResponse)

                    for url in currentResponse {
                        var urls: NSString = url as NSString
//                        println(images)
                        var photoUrls = NSURL.URLWithString(urls)

                        var err: NSError?
                        var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(photoUrls,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
                        var photos = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }


                    //                println(currentResponse)
                    //                self.currentResponse = currentResponse as NSArray
//                    self.photoCount = currentResponse.count as Int
//                    println(self.photoCount)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.photoCount = currentResponse.count as Int!
                        self.collectionView!.reloadData()
                        //                    self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.temperature)"
                        //                    self.iconView.image = currentWeather.icon!
                        //                    self.currentTimeLabel.text = "At \(currentWeather.currentTime!) it is"
                        //                    self.humidityLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.humidity)"
                        //                    self.percipitationLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.precipProbability)"
                        //                    self.summeryLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.summary)"
                        //
                        //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                        //
                        //                    self.refreshButton.hidden = false
                    })

                } else {

                    let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "I got 99 problems but a bitch ain't one", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
                    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                    networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)
                    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                    networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)

                    self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        //Stop refresh animation
                        //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                        //                    self.refreshButton.hidden = false

                    })

                }

            })

            downloadTask.resume()

        }
```

You can see in the getData() function that I have a for in loop, that loops through an array of urls, changes these urls to UIImages and assigns this to a global variable named photos.

```
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell
            println(photos)
//            cell.textLabel.text = "Text"
            cell.imageView.image = photos
//            cell.imageView.backgroundColor = colorWheel.randomColor()

            return cell
        }
    }
```

You can see in this collectionview function I am trying to display the images by assigning my photos variable (my loops of urls now UIImages) to the imageView cell. Nothing happens I just get a white screen on my IOS simulator but my print statement prints out all the images I am trying to display!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are assigning the image to a local variable named photos not the instance variable but more fundamentally you should store the retrieved image into an array as you cannot assume that the photo you have just loaded will be the one that is needed in cellaforItemAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the images into a NSMutableArray when you are parsing the response coming from the API. The modified code will look something similar to this:

```
var photos = NSMutableArray()
```

In the for loop where you assign the received image data you will have...

```
photos.addObject(UIImage(data:imageData))
```

And in the `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` function you will load the image like so:

```
cell.imageView.image = photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Your collection view should start displaying images now, however, you should also take into consideration the delay generated by the loading of each image and also the time it takes to reload them. You should consider using a caching class in order to cache the images you already downloaded so the user won't have to reload them when it refreshes or reloads the app.

A good library for caching, that works as intended, is SAMCache, and you can find it here: https://github.com/soffes/SAMCache. The implementation is fairly simple and to the point.